# Kinect Scaling in C++

Tags: c++, kinect

I am experimenting with the kinect, however I am having some problems with scaling. The below is code from the kinect-kcb and although the face tracking works for the 'mesh' I am having problems returning the scaling value for my own classes. The below code returns a correct rotation and translation which function perfectly, but the scale only ever returns 1 for a long period (despite the mesh clearly changing size) and then slowly gets smaller 0.98... etc but clearly not correct scaling values.

```
float scale;
float rotation[ 3 ];
float translation[ 3 ];
hr = mResult->Get3DPose( &scale, rotation, translation );
if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
    Vec3f r( rotation[ 0 ], rotation[ 1 ], rotation[ 2 ] );
    Vec3f t( translation[ 0 ], translation[ 1 ], translation[ 2 ] );

    face.mPoseMatrix.translate( t );
    face.mPoseMatrix.rotate( r );
    face.mPoseMatrix.translate( -t );
    face.mPoseMatrix.translate( t );
    face.mPoseMatrix.scale( Vec3f::one() * scale );
}
```

This scale value is used repeatedly thoughout the code, but does not seem to change often enough (example functions - not in order):

```
hr = mModel->Get3DShape( shapeUnits, numShapeUnits, animationUnits, numAnimationUnits, scale, rotation, translation, pts, numVertices );

hr = mModel->GetProjectedShape( &mConfigColor, mSensorData.ZoomFactor, viewOffset, shapeUnits, numShapeUnits, animationUnits, 
                            numAnimationUnits, scale, rotation, translation, pts, numVertices );
```

The kinect has a function FaceModel.Scale(), however this only returns a constant value which I assume is the initial scaling value for the 3D model, and then I assumed the above scaling value would change as the user moved closer and further away from the camera.

Comment: so im guessing you goal is to use a scale value to try and judge distance from the camera?

Comment: I eventually found the z values for the 3D model (was hoping there was a neater way). Thanks for your help :).

Answer (score 1):

The method [IFTResult::Get3DPose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.facetracking.iftresult.get3dpose.aspx) among other things, gives you the face scale value. If it is equal to 1.0 then the face scale is equal to the loaded 3D model (so nothing to do?).

If when reloading the 3d model, the face value is not equal to 1.0 then you need to do work on the model.

have you tried outputting some debug info of what IFTResult::Get3DPose assigns to pScale?

its also possible that the system is failing to track, you can check this with [IFTResult::GetStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.facetracking.iftresult.getstatus.aspx).

It may be that what you are after is the magnitude of the [face rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.facetracking.iftresult.getfacerect.aspx). This would scale with the proximity of the image subject.

[Heres](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/394975/How-To-Use-Kinect-Face-Tracking-SDK) a relevant code project link.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. That is what I have been doing. I must be miss understanding but pScale outputs 1.0 even when the model is changing size and then jumps to, say 0.984683 for a while, even though the model continues to rapidly change size etc. It does not seem to behave as expected? My debug looks somthing like pScale = 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 9.8..., 9.8,...,9.8...,9.8 despite a constantly moving user.

Comment: is it possible you are interested in the magnitude of the face rectangle, i think the scale value we have been discussing relates to 3d geometry

Comment: I was concerned about this. I think I know what you mean. I assume the best way is just to calculate it manually then. Thanks for you help :).

Comment: yea shouldnt be too hard tho. Take the area of the rectangle (len x wid) and divide it by the total area

Comment: Yep, didnt realise there was a getBounds (easy way to get the rectangle) function! That solved a lot of problems. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As getBounds is effected by rotation there does not seem to be a way to get a reliable area reading either?...The mesh is also subject to animation changes as far as I can tell.

Comment: did you try [GetFaceRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.facetracking.iftresult.getfacerect.aspx). Which would give you a [rect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5ch4fda.aspx) struct

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have made clearer, getBounds is the kinect commom bridge call to GetFaceRect :( It returns a 2D rectangle projected over the 3d mask so would only work for scale if the user looked straight ahead.